# How to restore MacBook Pro to factory settings? Prohibited sign on boot

Tags: macos, install, recovery

Because I am selling my old MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2011) and, for this reason, restore it to the factory settings. I have followed the steps for this. First the discs were erased which only partially succeeded. In the next step "reinstall macOS" I now get a gray screen and I can't get out (even after I turned off the laptop).

How can I proceed from here?

[image]

Comment: point taken:Because I am selling my old MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2011) and, for this reason, restore it to the factory settings.

I have followed the steps for this. First the discs were erased which only partially succeeded. In the next step "reinstall macOS" I now get a gray screen and I can't get out (even after I turned off the laptop). Hellup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to install an OS on Mac (prohibited sign)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/324235/unable-to-install-an-os-on-mac-prohibited-sign). https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/223342/prohibited-sign-cant-boot-after-trying-to-open-raspian-sd-card may also help.

Answer (score 1):

These links may help:

1) https://mackeeper.com/blog/post/473-step-by-step-guide-to-reset-mac-to-factory-settings/

2) https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/reset-mac-3494564/

3) https://macpaw.com/how-to/factory-reset-mac

Comment: It's better to explain what those links say in your answer, rather than just linking to another site. If those sites go down, then this answer will be worthless.